# Re-modelling maxflow-mincost to lose negative edge weights

Tags: algorithm, boost, graph

Let's say I have a problem simplified as following:

> "A producer `Pi` can produce a certain amount `ai` of items at cost `ci` per item. A consumer `Ck` can consume an amount `bk` at a profit of `pk` per item.

And we're interested in the maxflow with maximum gain / minimum loss and we intend to get that by using either BGL's [successive_shortest_path_nonnegative_weights](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/successive_shortest_path_nonnegative_weights.html) or its [cycle_canceling](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/cycle_canceling.html).

We should be able to model this by connecting source `S` to each `Pi` with an edge of capacity `ai` and a weight of `ci`.

We then connect each `Pi` to every `Ck` with an edge of capacity `bk` and weight `-pk`.

Lastly, we connect each `Ck` to target `T` with an edge of capacity `bk` and cost `0`.

After running cycle_canceling on that graph, we can get two values: `maxflow` will yield the maximum units sold and `-mincost` will represent total gain/loss.

We obviously cannot use successive_shortest_path_nonnegative_weights because - well, the name already states it.

It has been brought to my attention, though, that cycle_canceling is much slower than the successive_shortest_path approach and that by re-formulating the problem, we can get rid of the negative weights.

However, I'm not sure how to re-design this. We obviously cannot simply add a constant to all edge weights because that could change a shortest path and thereby falsify the result. Yet we must somehow reflect the fact that taking certain edges adds to the total costs, whereas taking others subtracts from them.

Any hints?

Comment: I'm not really following your problem. The way you phrased it, producer `i` can sell to consumer `i` only and consumer `i` can consume from producer `i` only. That problem would be trivial to solve though, so I probably misunderstand.

Comment: Producer ``i`` can sell to *any* consumer and vice-versa, consumer ``i`` can consume from *any* producer. I really should have chosen different indices, sorry for the confusion. It should be clearer, now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird problem for min-cost max flow. Better to sort the producers by cost increasing, sort the consumers by profit decreasing, and then repeatedly have the first residual producer send to the first residual consumer as long as there would be benefit. If you want to get super fancy, there's an O(n)-time algorithm that resembles your favorite median-finding algorithm.

EDIT: Because there are hidden reasons to use min-cost max flow (please don't make a habit of this; algorithm design is especially prone to the XY problem), what you can do is reweight the arcs as follows (this is a standard trick, used in, e.g., Johnson's algorithm).

Use an algorithm (e.g., Bellman--Ford) that can handle negative weights to compute distances d(v) from S to each vertex v. Now, update the weight w(u->v) of arc u->v to d(u) + w(u->v) - d(v), which is guaranteed non-negative, while the total relative weight of each path from S to T remains unchanged up to an additive constant (the d terms telescope).

Comment: As I said, it's simplified. And while I appreciate your input, I'm really looking for a way to turn this into a mincost-maxflow kind of thing without negative edge weights.